# Share variables from a deployment job to a normal job AZURE PIPELINE

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, pipeline

I'm traying to share a variable between a deploy job and a normal job in azure pipelines, when i try to print the variable im getting echo is off error.

Hey guys i´m having the next problem with azure pipelines

```
stages:

- stage: Stage
  jobs:
  - deployment: Staging
    displayName: Stage the WebApp
    environment: 
      name: 'Windows10'
      resourceName: Lxxxxxx
      resourceType: virtualMachine
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - powershell: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myStageOutputVar;isOutput=true]variable"
            name: printvar

- stage: Swap
  dependsOn: Stage
  variables:
    myVarfromStage: $[ stageDependencies.Stage.Staging.outputs['Windows10.printvar.myStageOutputVar'] ]
  jobs:
  - deployment: Production
    displayName: Swap to production
    environment: 
      name: 'Windows10'
      resourceName: Lxxxxxx
      resourceType: virtualMachine
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - script: echo $(myVarfromStage)
```

and im getting the next log when running the pipeline

```
Starting: CmdLine
==============================================================================
Task         : Command line
Description  : Run a command line script using Bash on Linux and macOS and cmd.exe on Windows
Version      : 2.231.1
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line
==============================================================================
Generating script.
Script contents: shell
echo 
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
"C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe" /D /E:ON /V:OFF /S /C "CALL "C:\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxxxx\xxxxxxxxxxxxx.cmd""
ECHO is off.
Finishing: CmdLine
```

and if i want to do this between a deployment and a job how can i do it.

Appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Use `job.task.variable` format instead of `environment.task.variable` for the outputs section in `Swap` stage.(Examples: [Support for output variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-jobs?view=azure-devops#support-for-output-variables))

```
- stage: Swap
  dependsOn: Stage
  variables:
    myVarfromStage: $[ stageDependencies.Stage.Staging.outputs['Staging.printvar.myStageOutputVar'] ]
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - "master"
  paths:
    include:
      - "azure-pipelines.yml"

stages:

- stage: Stage
  jobs:
  - deployment: Staging
    displayName: Stage the WebApp
    environment: 
      name: 'Windows10'
      resourceName: Lxxxxxx
      resourceType: virtualMachine
      # name: test
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - powershell: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myStageOutputVar;isOutput=true]variable"
            name: printvar

- stage: Swap
  dependsOn: Stage
  variables:
  - name: myVarfromStage
    value: $[ stageDependencies.Stage.Staging.outputs['Staging.printvar.myStageOutputVar'] ]
  jobs:
  - deployment: Production
    displayName: Swap to production
    environment: 
      name: 'Windows10'
      resourceName: Lxxxxxx
      resourceType: virtualMachine
      # name: test
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - script: echo $(myVarfromStage)
```

[image]

[Docs reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-jobs?view=azure-devops).